# how to get all points contained in the area of an object of any shape

Tags: collision-detection, 3d

how would I get points contained by objects, so that I can check for intersections of points, and I also ask myself if checking for intersections each frame would be too CPU intensive?

Comment: In continuous space, there's an infinite number of points inside any contained area/volume, so enumerating them all wouldn't make sense. Are you looking for only the lattice points of a grid with some discrete spacing, or only the vertex points of an object represented as a triangle mesh? Are there any constraints on the shapes of your objects - for instance, are they always boxes or spheres, or are they always convex? More restrictive constraints tend to enable faster optimizations, while [the most general case can be very slow indeed](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/205424/39518).

Comment: What is your goal? This sounds like what you would look into if you wanted to implement a naïve take on Minkowski addition for example for GJK. If that is the case, might this help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ajv46BSqcK4

Comment: If two objects are intersecting and roll back to previous positions to prevent intersections, then how would they roll back if they are intersecting on the first frame, is it that one object get pushed to the closest side?

Comment: Are you looking for how to compute the "Minimum Separation Vector" or "Minimum Translation Vector" for [tag:collision-resolution]?